# Factoring under a 4th power

Tags: factoring

Show that 
$$\left( a + b \right) ^ 4 = b^4 \left( \frac{a}{b} + 1 \right) ^4$$

---

Its clear without an exponent

$$\left( a + b \right) = b \left( \frac{a}{b} + 1 \right) $$

but I'm not sure why should it hold to the $n$th power

Comment: $(xy)^4=x^4y^4$

Comment: expand $(a+b)^4$ and $(\frac{a}{b} +1)^4$, then multiply the second by $b^4$. you should get the same result

Comment: $(xy)^4 = x^4y^4$. (@lulu was here 30 seconds sooner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

(1)  If $a = b$, then $a^n = b^n$ for all *nonnegative* integers $n$.

(2)  $(ab)^n = {a^n}{b^n}$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$\left( a + b \right) ^ 4 = \left(b \left( \frac{a}{b} + 1 \right)\right)^4 =b^4 \left( \frac{a}{b} + 1 \right) ^4$ assuming comutative multiplication